# Is there an LLVM backend for IL code according to IEC61131-3?

Tags: llvm, plc, iec61131-3

Does anybody know about a **LLVM backend which outputs IL** (instruction list, also known as AWL) according **to IEC 61131-3**?

Background: I have an algorithm written in C and want to run it on an industrial PLC, which unfortunatelly is not capable to process C code (some other PLCs are able to do). One possible way I thought of would be to compile the C code to IL, which then could be imported into the PLC.

If there is no IL backend for LLVM, what do you think: is it technically possible to write one and how much effort does this mean?

I'm new to all this stuff of LLVM and so on, but it seems for me that IL is quite similar to assembler.

Comment: Such questions are explicitly off-topic. And it is apparently not related to C.

Comment: @Olaf not necessarily. Emscripten works this way - produce Javascript from LLVM IR. So, alx, this is possible technically, but effort depends on complexity of that IL.

Comment: @arrowd: How is that in any way related to my comment?

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Olaf, it is related to the first, unedited post...

Comment: @arrowd, I think it is quite simmilar to Assembler and not very complex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_list). Maybe someone with some experience in IL and LLVM will answer, too.